# Python: changing .py file to .exe

Tags: python

I need some help with changing .py file to .exe file. I am trying to do it with cx_Freeze module, i managed to do the setup.py file, the only problem is, i dont know what should i put in my command prompt?

setup.py file looks like this:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"include_files": ["postevanka.ui,beep.wav,gang.wav"]}

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "Poštevanka",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "Postevanka",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("postevanka.py", base=base)])
```

Answer (score 2):

Install Py2exe and create a setup script:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console = ['script.py'])
```

Py2exe is much simpler.

Comment: may be, but its only for python version 2.7 and lower.

Comment: No, they recently added Python 3 support. See the [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2exe/0.9.2.2) page.

Comment: alright, got it, but i have no idea what to do with the code you posted above.

Comment: If this answer has helped you, and it seems to have indeed helped you, then please consider upvoting it and selecting it as your official answer.

Comment: After putting `script.py` and `setup.py` in the same directory, run `python setup.py py2exe` in command prompt.

Comment: i guess script.py is the code i did in pycharm, for the program? but what if i've got 2 files, one is a .py file, and the other one is .ui file (from QtDesigner)

Comment: and the cmd says that: 'python is not recognized as an internal or external command'

Comment: Python is probably not in your system path. What version are you running?

Comment: 3.4.1. and what should i do if i have 2 files? or does it put them together automatically?

Comment: Let me write a new answer this is going to be wordy.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to do.

1. Find the directory in which your script.py is.
2. Move your setup.py to this directory and please keep this window open.
3. Hold shift, right click this directory, and open command window here.
4. In the command window type: `C:\Python34\python.exe setup.py py2exe`

Comment: I don't know what holding shift and right clicking should do, but it works same as just right clicking on it.

Comment: It gives you more options in the context menu, with a command prompt option.

Comment: Not in my case i guess. Does this apply only to Mac maybe?

Comment: No, just Windows. Any how copy the directory, open command prompt, and type `cd path` where `path` is the full path for the directory. Tell me once you have that working.

Comment: How is it going @RokDolinar?

Comment: yeah, i did it, what should i do now?

Comment: Type `C:\Python34\python.exe setup.py py2exe`. Tell me what happens.

Comment: Same thing as before, im not sure how can this work, i mean syntax is wrong?

Comment: Okay, this has seriously been going to long. Place `setup.py` and `script.py` in the same folder and run the setup through the command line. How hard can it be?

Comment: i guess too hard for me.

Comment: Do you know how to edit the system path? Right click `My Computer` and hit `Properties`. Hit `Advanced system settings` and then `Environment variables`. Find the path variable and add `C:\Python34\;` to whatever is there.

Comment: When you're done with that go to the command prompt, set the directory to the folder that contains your scripts and run `python setup.py py2exe`.

Answer (score 0):

try using pyinstaller

in command window, cd to the folder where your python file is located and simply type the following command by replacing 'myscript.py' with the name of your python file

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed myscript.py
```

this will create a new folder named "dist" in the current directory. This folder will contain the newly created exe file with the same name as your .py file

another option is to use the following command in the command window

```
pyinstaller myscript.py
```

this will create a folder named after your python file inside the dist folder. the new folder will contain the exe file along with copies of all the modules and libraries you have used in your code and some additional files needed for the exe to run.

i suggest to use the first method which creates a single file which can be shared without any hassles.

refer https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html if you need more information regarding that.

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

You can create `start.bat` file and use it like exe

```
"C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe" "C:\package\script.py"
```